# Apache httpd build with mod_evasive failed

Tags: c, apache, makefile, centos, mod-evasive

I am trying to compile and build an `apache httpd` server with `mod_evasive`. I got an error on the make stage:

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `mod_evasive24.c.lo', needed by `libmod_evasive24.c.la'.  Stop.
```

Anybody has an idea what this error means and how i can resolved.

Comment: That's not much information to figure out what failed. I can run `make oombawoomba` and I will get an error message similar to yours `make: *** No rule to make target 'oombawoomba'. Stop`.

Comment: Read the `Makefile` and find the rule to create the target `mod_evasive24.c.lo` and you will be golden the next time you re-run the command you ran.

Comment: Do you have `apr` and `apr-devel` installed by any chance? Those are needed when building apache modules.